# i want to create like this app bar on Flutter

Tags: flutter, web

Dears

I want to create this template on flutter web with extended body

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmjPj.png)

Answer (score 0):

is it for desktop or web application ?
I think you have to create your custom app bar using PreferredSizeWidget
I suggest to see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69693904/9431171

Comment: Web applecation